# If statement for VBA in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to make a template for doing our passdown in Outlook.  I want it to say "Day Shift" in the subject line if it is between the hours of 0700 and 1900, and "Night Shift" otherwise.  How can this be done.

What I have so far:

```
Sub MakeItem()
    Dim objMail As MailItem
    Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Passdown1.oft")
    newItem.Subject = "D1D NXE Day Shift Passdown " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
    newItem.Display

    Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Select Case Hour(Now)`, `Case 7 To 18` for Day shift, `Case Else` for Night shift. `End Select`, then change the Subject field within the Case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my Comment, here is what you do...

```
Sub MakeItem()
    Dim objMail As MailItem
    Dim sShift As String ' Add this
    Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Passdown1.oft")
    ' Check hours
    Select Case Hour(Now)
        Case 7 To 18 ' Day shift until 18:59:59
            sShift = "Day"
        Case Else
            sShift = "Night"
    End Select
    ' Setup Subject replacing the <SHIFT>
    newItem.Subject = Replace("D1D NXE <SHIFT> Shift Passdown " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy"), "<SHIFT>", sShift)
    newItem.Display

    Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could do this in one line:

```
newItem.Subject = String.Format("D1D NXE {0} Shift Passdown {1}", If(Date.Now.Hour >= 7 AndAlso Date.Now.Hour < 19, "Day", "Night"), Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify whatever condition for condition an specify a whatever statement to be excectued when condition is true

```
If condition [ Then ]
    [ statements ]
[ ElseIf elseifcondition [ Then ]
    [ elseifstatements ] ]
[ Else
    [ elsestatements ] ]
End If

' Single-line syntax:
If condition Then [ statements ] [ Else [ elsestatements ] ]
```

**condition**

Required. Expression. Must evaluate to True or False, or to a data type that is implicitly convertible to Boolean.

If the expression is a Nullable Boolean variable that evaluates to Nothing, the condition is treated as if the expression is not True, and the Else block is executed.

**Then**

Required in the single-line syntax; optional in the multiple-line syntax.

**statements**

Optional. One or more statements following If...Then that are executed if condition evaluates to True.

**elseifcondition**

Required if ElseIf is present. Expression. Must evaluate to True or False, or to a data type that is implicitly convertible to Boolean.

**elseifstatements**

Optional. One or more statements following ElseIf...Then that are executed if elseifcondition evaluates to True.

**elsestatements**

Optional. One or more statements that are executed if no previous condition or elseifcondition expression evaluates to True.

**End If**

Terminates the If...Then...Else block.